# Mobile and Multi-Language URL Rewrite Together

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a multi-language website. And i decided to prepare mobil view. Responsive is not good solution for me. I want to create mobile view for my website like m.example.com

My language websites are like

example.com/tr/
example.com/en/

I'm rewriting "?lang=tr" as "/tr/". What happens if i want a mobile view.

script.php?lang=tr&view=mobile as m.example.com/tr/

Here is my htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.tr$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com.tr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes/xml/mediaxml.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^sitemap.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes/xml/google.php$
RewriteRule ^(tr|en|fr|de)/(.+).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(tr|en|fr|de)/$ /?lang=$1

#Ürün Detay Sayfası
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?pid=$2&lang=tr
RewriteRule ^(tr|en|fr|de)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ product.php?pid=$3&lang=$1

#Kategori Sayfaları
#RewriteRule ^(tr|en|fr|de)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-c([0-9]+)/$ product.php?cid=$3&lang=$1
#RewriteRule ^(tr|en|fr|de)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-m([0-9]+)/$ product.php?mcid=$3&lang=$1

#Sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap_(tr|en|fr|de)\.xml$ sitemap.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^google\.xml$ /includes/xml/google.php [L]

#Print [a-z]{2}
RewriteRule ^(tr|en|fr|de)/(.+).php?print=([a-z]) /$2.php?print=$3&lang=$1 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I failed rewriting Mobile and Multi-Language URLs together. How can i do that ? I always get Internal Server Error 500